# Add wireshark into my code instead of install on the machine

Tags: c#, wireshark

I have built an application which handles with wireshark files (pcap files) and in order to show statistics uses Wireshark exe file (capinfos, tshark etc.)
My question is "Is there any options to add Wireshark into my code instead of installing Wireshark on the machine ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Wireshark source code in GPL context, look [here](http://www.wireshark.org/download/docs/developer-guide-us.pdf) for compile instructions and license information.

Comment: is it easy to do it ? can i find on the network examples how to do it ?

Comment: Look at 6.3 6.4 from manual, if you need only to handle files, you can use their Wiretap library, but as I understand its not good documented. So there are two ways - look at source code of Wiretap for interface of functions and use better documented Winpcap's wrapper as @zmbq said to work with raw data.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) which, if I recall correctly, let's you access pcap files.

Comment: i am using Pcan.net DLL's but i am using Wireshrk statistics so i need Wireshark on my machine

Comment: Oh. So you can either implement the statistics yourself, or do what @Aleksey suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. Because as far as I know, there's no portable version of wireshark. And Wireshark works on pretty low level. But as it is opensource so there must should be source code available. so you can use that code in your code. But it should be that easy also.

Comment: i am new development so i don't have so much experience, it's easy to implement ?

Comment: well, i would not try this myself. :D :D :D. this should be not that easy. But still if try that you can learn a lot of things.